# ActionMaps in java

Tags: java, swing

```
public class XXX 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JComponent comp = new JTable(); // some panel or table
        comp.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F4"), "xxxaction");
        comp..getActionMap().put("xxxaction", new XXXAction());
    }

    public class XXXAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
             // Something;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to execute the invoked action XXXAction() without pressing 'F4' using the ActionMap lookup??

Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General code would be:

```
Action action = component.getActionMap().get("...");

if (action != null)
{
    ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(component, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
    action.actionPerformed( ae );
}
```

You will need to know if a String value is required for the ActionEvent.

Comment: But.. one thing.. what is that 'command string' in ActionEvent(..) mean?? Now, I am giving an empty string and things seem to work. Is that fine to leave it as empty??

Comment: Generally it will be empty. However some Actions may require a paremeter. For example, I believe the default FontSize Action from the editor kit need a string that can be converted to an integer value (8, 10, 12...) to be used as the font size. If you you are creating a custom Action you can control whether a String value is required or not.

Comment: Oh.. Now I get it.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two possible ways:

1. Register your action with a `Component` such as a `JButton`.  That way the `Action` will be invoked when you manually click the button with the mouse.
2. Define a method `invokeAction()` on your class `XXX` that calls the action, either by retrieving the action from the `ActionMap` via its key, or by retaining an explicity instance variable reference to it as well as placing it in the `ActionMap`.